# Section by section comparison between files

Tags: shell-script, file-comparison

I have SQL query output from 2 different databases in 2 files. Section-wise, it will be in the same order on both files, but the results will differ.

I need to compare section-wise and report it section-wise. Please let me know if there is any other way to add more detail.

sample content of output files

---

```
Section : database Characterset information 

PARAMETER                 VALUE                                                                                                         
========================= ==========                                                                                                    
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS      BYTE                                                                                                          
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET    AL16UTF16                                                                                                     
NLS_CHARACTERSET          AL32UTF8                                                                                                      

Section : table row count 

OWNER                     TABLE_NAME                               COUNT  
========================= =================================== ==========  
HR                        REGIONS                                      4  
HR                        LOCATIONS                                   23  
HR                        DEPARTMENTS                                 27  
HR                        JOBS                                        19  
HR                        EMPLOYEES                                  107  
HR                        JOB_HISTORY                                 10  
HR                        COUNTRIES                                   25  
 
7 rows selected.  

Section : oracle patching information. 

no rows selected
```

Desired Output

---

```
Section : database characterset information 

PARAMETER                 VALUE                                                                                                         
========================= ==========                                                                                                    
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET    AL16UTF16                                                                                                     

Section : table row count 

OWNER                     TABLE_NAME                               COUNT  
========================= =================================== ==========  
HR                        REGIONS                                      4
```

Comment: that honestly sounds like you used the wrong export formate when asking your oracle DB for a dump of these system tables. Had you used an SQL format, you could just use your SQL skills and compare them as what they are – tables of of tabular data.